# How to open the Quota Entries list for a given drive from a shortcut or command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, shortcuts, quota

Is it possible to open the Quota Entries list for a given drive from a shortcut or the command line in Windows? And if so, how?

I'm not talking about managing quota entries from the command line (`fsutil quota`), I'm looking for a way to get directly to the Quota Entries GUI rather than going through My Computer → right-click on a drive → Properties → Quota tab → Show Quota Settings → Quota Entries...

I managed to find out (using Process Explorer) that the backend process is dllhost.exe, and the DLL in question should be dskquoui.dll, so it should be possible to run it directly with rundll32.exe, but I'm not sure of the exact syntax. Any ideas?

Comment: Surely a win guru has some insight into launching a specific sub-gui given a dll. I think it depends on dll though and may be impossible for this particular application. Would be nice to see some kind of reference on this though. Anyone?